# Formatting floating numbers to certain length

Tags: java, format

I want to limit my numbers to 7 significant figures (I believe this is known as significant digits in American English) with a maximum of 5 decimal places but I am ensure on how to do this.

I am currently using `%-7.5f` but this always prints 5 decimal places, even if those places aren't significant.

I.e. `3.75` becomes `3.75000`

Here's some examples to try and further clarify what I am after:

`3097.0` -> `3097`

`10.39596` -> `10.396`

`79.6103426` -> `79.61034`

I.e. No leading or trailing 0s, 7 significant figures and at most 5 decimal places.

I'm trying to do this as I am working on upgrading an old program written in QBasic and this is how it formats it's floating point numbers when they are displayed. I want my Java code to output the numbers this way simply to make it easier to compare the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat` for this

```
    double value1 = 10.39596;
    double value2 = 79.6103426;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
    System.out.print(df.format(value1));
    System.out.print(df.format(value2));
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use DecimalFormat for this purpose

```
new DecimalFormat("#.#####").format(d)
```

this pattern limits fractional part to max 5 digits

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.#####");
System.out.println(format.format(79.6103426));
```